# Crear sub menu con js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Necesito ayuda para crear un sub-menu con *js*.

Yo recupero un *JSON* desde un página que es algo así:

```
[{"ip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","puerto":"xxxx","gid":"2","active":"2","queryport":"xxxx"},
{"ip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","puerto":"xxxxx","gid":"3","active":"2","queryport":"xxxx"},
{"ip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","puerto":"xxxxx","gid":"2","active":"1","queryport":"xxxx"}]
```

Y en *node js* tengo un código así

```
 var obj = JSON.parse(num);
 var content = "<ul>";
   for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; ++i) {
    if (obj[i].gid == "2"){ 
      var content2 ="<li class=\"language-selector__item u-uppercase cod1\"><a href=\"#\">"+ 
      obj[i].puerto +"</a></li>";
     var content1 = "</ul>";
      document.getElementById('mencod1').innerHTML = content + content2 + content1;
      }
  }
```

En HTML tengo un

```
<div id="mencod1"></div>
```

Donde ahí entraría el sub-menu. El tema es que necesito que cada "obj[i].puerto" sea un sub-menu pero no encuentro la forma.

Hace unos días hice una pregunta que creía que me iba a ayudar pero no me dio resultado.

Si alguien sabe que método se puede implementar se lo agradecería.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Cuando dices *submenú* te refieres a una lista tipo `<ul>` dentro de tu `<li>`? Deberías mostrar un ejemplo de salida deseada a partir de los datos obtenidos. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun lo que veo del codigo hay un problema con la iteracion y el cierre del listado:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(num);
var content = "<ul>";
var content2 = "";
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; ++i) {
    if (obj[i].gid == "2"){ 
      content2 +="<li class=\"language-selector__item u-uppercase cod1\"><a href=\"#\">"+obj[i].puerto +"</a></li>";          
      }
}
var content1 = "</ul>";
document.getElementById('mencod1').innerHTML = content + content2 + content1;
```

La iteracion debe generar el contenido del listado, y luego de la iteracion conectar las partes, de otro modo se generaria solo una entrada y se sobreescribiria en cada iteracion.

Comment: Muchas gracias, con esto pude resolver el problema. como lo pasaste funciona correctamente, y crea el sub-menu. Muchas gracias.